# How to change Postman environment in pre-request script?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I'm having several collections of REST queries and tests in postman, and for each collection I've created a set of environment variables.
I wish to make sure the right environment is selected before running the tests.
Is there a way to automatically switch between environments in pre-request script section?

Comment: You set variables for Collections, so the best course of action, would be to have one collection with one set of variables for -dev, same for -stage and -production.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't switch environments from the pre-request script section.

That being said you can still check the name of the current environment with `pm.environment.name;` and stop the execution if it's not the one you expect, for example:

```
if(pm.environment.name !== "dev") {
   postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables names by environment and specially the url of your REST API.